# How to grab apollo client cache content and use it in a query as an input type?

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo-client

I am developing a react native application with apollo client and I need to have 2 screens:
Screen A: displays a list of profiles
Screen B: displays some filters which have to be applied to Screen A

So my idea was to use apollo client cache to save the state of the filters in screen B, and then come back to screen A and somehow refetch with the new filters applied.

Since there are a couple of filters that I need to send on each request to the server, I also was thinking about using an input type so I can send my filters in the form of an object instead of a list of comma-separated parameters.

So looking at the docs from apollo client, there is a section to manage the local stage. In there, I found a sub-section called **Using @client fields as variables**. Basically, this part tells you how to grab whatever filters were stored in the cache and send it as part of the query.

However, I always get the following error:
**Invariant Violation: Missing selection set for an object of type ProfileParameters returned for query field profileParameters**

some code:

This is how I initialized the cache-store, for now, it only contains page and pageSize but it will contain more parameters.

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  cacheRedirects: {
    Query: {
      profile: (_, {id}, {getCacheKey}) =>
        getCacheKey({__typename: 'Profile', id: id}),
    },
  },
});

cache.writeData({
  data: {
    profileParameters: {
      __typename: 'ProfileParameters',
      page: 0,
      pageSize: 25,
    },
  },
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://192.168.1.102:3000/graphql',
  cache: cache,
  resolvers: {},
});
```

And this is the query component and the query:

```
const PROFILES_QUERY = gql`
      query getFilteredProfiles($type: String, $parameters: ProfileParameters) {
        profileParameters @client @export(as: "parameters")
        profiles(type: $type, parameters: $parameters) {
          id
          name
          termOfEntry
          sport
          sportPosition
          gpa
          avatarUrl
          imageUrl
          nationality
          countryOfResidence
          dateOfBirth
          annualBudget
          career
          satScore
          toeflScore
          graduationDate
        }
      }
    `;
          <Query
            query={PROFILES_QUERY}
            variables={{
              type: this.PROFILE_TYPE,
            }}> 
               ...
          </Query>
```

There is a **type** variable that is being passed in the variables object. That comes from a local variable in the class.

Also, screen B does not exist yet, but the cache is being initialized and I want to read whatever is in there so I can send those filters to the server.